# What is the relation between data-directed programming and dynamic dispatch?

Tags: data-structures

I was reading SICP and it talks about Data-directed programming.

To me is sounds like generating a vtable or a dispatch table explicitly, and then looking up to it explicitly too. The programmer responsible for the data and operation implementation is responsible to add the proper entries to that table and the advantage is that the dispatch procedure doesn't change when new data types are added to the program, achieving additivity of the code.

This seems like a lot of work to achieve a dynamic dispatch, I'm wrong? I was reading that racket has multimethods for example, so I can dispatch based on type. Doesn't this achieve the same goal of Data-directed programming?

Is Type-directed programming the same as Data-directed programming?